# $l_1$ distance between $n$th fold product distributions $p^n$ and $q^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

Let $p$ and $q$ be two probability distributions on a finite alphabet $\mathcal{X}$. The $l_1$ distance between them is defined as
$$l_1(p, q) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} |p(x) - q(x)|$$

Consider $n$th fold product distribution of $p$, namely $p^n$ given by
$$p^n(x^n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)$$
for all $x^n \in \mathcal{X}^n$.

Can we express $l_1(p^n, q^n)$ in terms of $l_1(p, q)$ or at least provide an upper or lower bound on $l_1(p^n, q^n)$ in terms of $l_1(p, q)$?

\begin{align}
l_1(p^n, q^n) &= \sum_{x^n \in \mathcal{X}^n} |p^n(x^n) - q^n(x^n)|\\
&= \sum_{x^n \in \mathcal{X}^n} \Bigg | \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i) - \prod_{i=1}^n q(x_i) \Bigg |
\end{align}

Comment: Your notation is confusing: I am assuming $x^n$ here represents an $n$-vector and not the $n$-fold power of some number. Also, is $\mathcal{X}$ a set containing the supports of both $P$ and $Q$? Furthermore, are you assuming $P$ and $Q$ are discrete?

Comment: $x^n$ is a sequence of length $n$: $x^n = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ where each $x_i \in \mathcal{X}$ . $\mathcal{X}$ contains the supports of both $p$ and $q$. Yes, $p$ and $q$ are discrete as evident by $\sum \limits_{x \in \mathcal{X}}$ as opposed to $\int_{x \in \mathcal{X}}$

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Consider first the case for $n=2$ and arbitrary product distributions $p_1 \times p_2$ and $q_1 \times q_2$

\begin{align*}
    l_1(p_1 \times p_2, q_1 \times q_2) &= \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} |p_1(x_1) p_2(x_2) - q_1(x_1) q_2(x_2)|\\
    &= \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} |p_1(x_1) p_2(x_2) - p_1(x_1) q_2(x_2) +  p_1(x_1) q_2(x_2) - q_1(x_1) q_2(x_2)|\\
    &= \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} |p_1(x_1)(p_2(x_2) - q_2(x_2))  + q_2(x_2) (p_1(x_1) - q_1(x_1))  |\\
    &\leq \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} p_1(x_1) |p_2(x_2) - q_2(x_2)| + \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2} q_2(x_2) |p_1(x_1) - q_1(x_1)|\\
    &=  \sum_{x_2}  |p_2(x_2) - q_2(x_2)| + \sum_{x_1}  |p_1(x_1) - q_1(x_1)|\\
    &= l_1(p_1, q_1) + l_1(p_2, q_2)
\end{align*}

This implies $$l_1(p^2, q^2) \leq 2 l_1(p, q)$$

Now use induction with similar arguments as before.